# iPhone animations - Moving a view in a circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewanimation

Is there a way to move a view around a center point without rotating it using the view animations?

```
   A

A  C  A

   A
```

Comment: The "smarty pants" way to do this:

At one level spin a view around it's own bottom left corner. (Or if you prefer another point further away along that line).

But, **at the same time, use another level to spin it around it's center** by the same amount of degrees in the other direction.

It's a **"ferris wheel"** method, if you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that big a deal to put an animation thread in and move it manually every frame so thats what I went with.

Answer (score 3):

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
    #define degreesToRadians(deg) (deg / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

manualy :

```
-(CGPoint)setPointToAngle:(int)angle center:(CGPoint)centerPoint radius:(double)radius
 {
    return CGPointMake(radius*cos(degreesToRadians(angle)) + centerPoint.x, radius*sin(degreesToRadians(angle)) + centerPoint.y);
 }
```

with animation something like this:

```
    int angle = 0; // start angle position 0-360 deg
    CGPoint center = self.view.center;
    CGPoint start = [self setPointToAngle:angle center:center radius:radius]; //point for start moving
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, start.x, start.y);

    for(int a =0;a<4;a++) //set path points for 90, 180, 270,360 deg form begining angle
    {
        angle+=45;
        expPoint = [self setPointToAngle:angle center:center radius:expRadius];
        angle+=45;
        start = [self setPointToAngle:angle center:center radius:radius];
        CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL,expPoint.x, expPoint.y, start.x, start.y);
    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    pathAnimation.path = path;
    [pathAnimation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationCubic];
    [pathAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    pathAnimation.duration = 14.0; 

    [MY_VIEW.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:nil];
```

also look at

```
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint, 
CGPathAddCurveToPoint, 
CGPathAddArcToPoint, 
CGPathAddArc
```

and others